# Mount partition sdb get message permission denied?

Tags: 12.04, mount, 8.04

I have 2 server with different ubuntu version,first server use ubuntu 8.04 and second server use ubuntu 12.04, now i want to use 2 HDD in first server ubuntu ver 8.04, so second server not function anymore just i take HDD in second server and i put in first server.. if i use fdisk-l all device has display on terminal,but i cant mount Sdb5 to home,sdb5 is ext4 file system.

I am trying mount sdb to directory home. but i got result message like this

```
bash: /dev/sdb5: Permission denied
```

I use this command to mount partition

```
/dev/sdb5 on /home/datadosen ext4
```

why i get permission denied even i already use chmod -R 777 in my directory home ?

thanks

Comment: your command is Wrong

Comment: Could you please list down what commands you use to mount?

Comment: When mounting you have to use `sudo` before mount command

Comment: i already as root in terminal

Answer (score 2):

To Mount a Drive

Check the file system using to see the filesystem informations ,

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5
```

Then change the journal Using

```
sudo tune2fs -j /dev/sda6
```

First Create a Directory inside home

```
 mkdir -p /home/datadosen
```

Then Mount Using

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /home/datadosen
```

Never Use 777 permission, It's a Security breach, Any one can modify your file's.

Comment: When you are root you don'e need to use sudo and note its sudo small s not Sudo this will not work

Comment: Thanks, to pointing out S as capital and he is not mentioned as he in root user.

Comment: No you use # before this means root. I mean you not the OP. If you don't mean that remove # from your commands

Comment: # mentioned for it's a command

Comment: Nope my friend # in terminal means root

Comment: You are very welcomed

Comment: still not work,i have 2 server with different ubuntu version,first server use ubuntu 8.04 and second server use ubuntu 12.04, now i want to use 2 HDD in first server in ubuntu ver 8.04, so second server not function anymore just i take HDD in second server and i put in first server..
if i use fdisk-l all device has display on terminal,but i cant mount Sdb5 to home,sdb5 is ext4 file system..

Comment: Sorry your Ubuntu 8.04 will not support ext4, Sure you have used Ext4 file system in Ubuntu 12.04 and now your trying to mount that in ext3, so its not supported one

Comment: try sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5 to see the filesystem informations ,
then sudo tune2fs -j /dev/sda6 then try to mount as before commands

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sudo` command with mount, because mounting requires root privileges.

**Example:**

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /home/datadozen
```

Also, you can add your user into `plugdev` group.

```
sudo adduser datadozen plugdev
```

Comment: still not work,i have 2 server with different ubuntu version,first server use ubuntu 8.04 and second server use ubuntu 12.04, now i want to use 2 HDD in first server in ubuntu ver 8.04, so second server not function anymore just i take HDD in second server and i put in first server.. if i use fdisk-l all device has display on terminal,but i cant mount Sdb5 to home,sdb5 is ext4 file system..